# Integrar php y mysql con front end

Tags: php

si tengo una pagina web hecha solo con html,css y javascript y quiero hacer uso de PHP y MySql, puedo usar codigo PHP en el archivo .html, he buscado y veo que tengo que crear la pagina con extencion .php y aqui ya puedo integrar archivos css y javascript. O como puedo desarrollar una web "completa" con front end y backed(html,css,javascript,php,mysql). O como seria el orden para desarrollarla, empezar por html,css,javascript,php y mysql o puedo hacer todo solo con php y mysql como base de datos?

Comment: Solo cambia la extensión del `index.html` por `index.php` para poder implementar código en Php... por cierto, a mi consideración, todo lo que es Front-End vendría siendo Html y CSS, y lo que es Php con Mysql es Back-End, el `Front` como lo quieres ver, colores, formas, de qué lado, tamaños etc y `Back` para procesos, consultas a la base de datos... pero hay variedad, podrías buscar información sobre lenguajes de desarrollo web destinados (en este caso) tanto al Back-End como el Front-End

Comment: Son demasiadas preguntas en una sola. Y son unas respuestas tan amplias como opinables, asi que mejor que vayas a buscar videos tutoriales de como crear una página web, y luego de como crear un front-end y un backend, y poco a poco lo irás descubriendo y practicando.

Comment: Vale, ya he creado front-end pero solo una carpeta con archivos html,css y javascript, y al usar php veo que se crea la carpeta en htdocs de xampp y a partir de ahi creamos lo que es el archivo con extension .php y los archivos css y javascript y lo abrimos en el localhost, pero lo que veo es que no puedo integrar codigo en el archivo .html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede utilizar una combinación de todo, pero para integrar PHP, debes utilizar la extensión `.php`.

Web Simple: index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Web con PHP</title>
<style>
h1 {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$holaMundo = "Hola Mundo";
?>
<h1><?php echo $holaMundo; ?><h1>

<script>
    console.log("Hola Mundo");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo, puede utilizar PHP junto a HTML, CSS y JavaScript.

En el caso de que quieras agregar MySQL, también puedes hacerlo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Web con PHP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php

// Conexión MySQL

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "miDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

<!-- HTML -->

Nombre: <?=$row['nombre'];?><br>
Email: <?=$row['email'];?>
<hr>

<!-- HTML -->

<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero sirva el ejemplo. Saludos